# Visual Studio 2015 freezes with Xamarin android project

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android

I have been facing a problem of freezing Visual Studio 2015 frequently during building a `Xamarin Android` project and each time I have to kill `Visual Studio` process and start the building process again then it will work. I'm facing this issue with two machines both of them are `Windows 10 Pro` .
I'm using:

- Visual Studio 2015 Community update 3.
- Xamarin 4.2.0
- Xamarin.Android 7.0.1.6

Comment: This is just to let you know I have a similar issue. VS would freeze after making changes to the XML files. No issues editing .cs files. It's really annoying, but I resorted to restarting Visual Studio myself after making changes to XML files and before building. 
Problem started after some recent update. Could not track down the issue.
No such issues with Xamarin.iOS.

Comment: are you using Team Foundation Server? Had the same problem and it added to the files write-protect attribute. I^ve selected all files in Explorer and unset this attribute and everythings worked like a charm again.

Comment: I am running the same versions as you and having the same issue. I'll build my Xamarin Android project and Visual Studio goes into indefinite hard freeze. The only way to recover is to force close and reopen Visual Studio.

Comment: I created a bug report here https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=46874

Comment: Check your files if they are write-protected. Had the same issue because the TeamFoundation server locked and then write-protected my files.

Comment: Before opening Visual Studio, can you try and delete the .vs folder present in the solution directory. Once deleted, try starting VS with the project and see if you are facing still facing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and can't find the source of why visual studio hangs while developing Xamarin android project.

Specs:

```
Visual Studio Professional 2015 with latest update
Windows 10 64-bit
Dev Express Included
ReSharper Installed
Visual Studio 2013 also installed on machine
16 GB Ram
Intel i7 6700 CPU 3.40 GHx
Git for source control
jdk1.7.0_55
Xamarin latest version
```

The designer also hangs crazy time
In event viewer I can see that vs studio hangs

The program devenv.exe version 14.0.25420.1 stopped interacting with Windows and was closed. To see if more information about the problem is available, check the problem history in the Security and Maintenance control panel

I tried the following attempts and did not helped me:

```
1.Reinstall (windows + visual studio).
2.Reinstall vs with Xamarin.
3.Update to latest version of Xamarin and vs 
4.I also deleted the C:\Users\ ...\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0 directory and i just
lost my settings and some configuration with no effect. Also VS extensions have been removed
5.Deleted my anti virus did not helped
6.No firewall anymore disabled it
7.Disabled windows defender
8.Removed Resharper
```

The only solution i have is :

Kill vs and restart... but this in annoying since to many times it hangs

Answer (score 0):

Before you go re-installing everything...

I've also experienced Visual Studio (2015 Update 3) hanging while starting a debug session into my Xamarin Android project.

It appears that Visual Studio is having some timing issue between the deployment and connecting to the debugger.  What is working for me...

1) Open Task Manager and **Kill Visual Studio** (because it's hung, and this is the only way I know how to get it out of this state), then...

2) **Keeping the Android Hyper-V instance running from my last debug attempt, re-open my project and start a new debug session**.

Perhaps Visual Studio is failing to connect to the [ADB (Android Debug Bridge)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt228282.aspx#ADB)?